# Electron: Add app icon to bottom right of the taskbar

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron, taskbar

I have just developed an electron app and a use suggested adding an icon to the bottom right of the task bar to easily open it and access it. I would like to add an icon to the area in the picture below:

[image: Taskbar Location]

I had a look in the electron [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/windows-taskbar) but could not find anything.

Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: That's called the system tray and Electron implements it [throught the `Tray` class](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/tray). Have a look at those docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That area is called the "system tray" and you can add a system tray icon for your electron app using Electron's Tray API. You can find the [documentation for the `Tray` class here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/tray) and may also take a look at [this tutorial](https://livebook.manning.com/book/electron-in-action/chapter-9/13).

Answer (score 1):

// Electron taskbar

```
const {app, Tray, Menu} = require('electron')

app.on('ready', () => {
  tray = new Tray(path.join(__dirname, 'icon/favicon.ico'))

  if (process.platform === 'win32' ) {
    tray.on('click', tray.popUpContextMenu)
  }

  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate ([
    {
      label: 'Exit',
      click() { app.quit()}
    },

    {  label: 'Help',
    click() { null; }}
  ])

  tray.setToolTip('AppName')
  tray.setContextMenu(menu)
})
```